# Grails plugins suddenly failing to download

Tags: maven, grails, plugins

My build machine just started reporting the following:

```
:::: ERRORS
SERVER ERROR: Connection timed out url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/tomcat/7.0.50/tomcat-7.0.50-sources.jar
SERVER ERROR: Backend is unhealthy url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/tomcat/7.0.50/tomcat-7.0.50-src.jar
SERVER ERROR: Connection timed out url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/tomcat/7.0.50/tomcat-7.0.50-javadoc.jar
SERVER ERROR: Connection timed out url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/7.0.50/tomcat-embed-core-7.0.50.pom
SERVER ERROR: Connection timed out url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/7.0.50/tomcat-embed-core-7.0.50.jar
SERVER ERROR: Backend is unhealthy url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-catalina-ant/7.0.50/tomcat-catalina-ant-7.0.50.pom
SERVER ERROR: Backend is unhealthy url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-catalina-ant/7.0.50/tomcat-catalina-ant-7.0.50.jar
SERVER ERROR: Connection timed out url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-jasper/7.0.50/tomcat-embed-jasper-7.0.50.pom
SERVER ERROR: Connection timed out url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-jasper/7.0.50/tomcat-embed-jasper-7.0.50.jar
SERVER ERROR: Backend is unhealthy url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-logging-log4j/7.0.50/tomcat-embed-logging-log4j-7.0.50.pom
SERVER ERROR: Connection timed out url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-logging-log4j/7.0.50/tomcat-embed-logging-log4j-7.0.50.jar
SERVER ERROR: Connection timed out url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/ecj/3.7.2/ecj-3.7.2.pom
SERVER ERROR: Connection timed out url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/ecj/3.7.2/ecj-3.7.2.jar
SERVER ERROR: Connection timed out url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/release/2.2.1/release-2.2.1-sources.jar
SERVER ERROR: Connection timed out url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/release/2.2.1/release-2.2.1-src.jar
SERVER ERROR: Connection timed out url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/release/2.2.1/release-2.2.1-javadoc.jar
SERVER ERROR: Connection timed out url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-ant-tasks/2.1.3/maven-ant-tasks-2.1.3.pom
SERVER ERROR: Backend is unhealthy url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-ant-tasks/2.1.3/maven-ant-tasks-2.1.3.jar
SERVER ERROR: Connection timed out url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/rest-client-builder/1.0.3/rest-client-builder-1.0.3-sources.jar
SERVER ERROR: Connection timed out url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/rest-client-builder/1.0.3/rest-client-builder-1.0.3-src.jar
SERVER ERROR: Connection timed out url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/rest-client-builder/1.0.3/rest-client-builder-1.0.3-javadoc.jar
```

I took those URLs and started to look for what happened.  The server is reporting a 404 on those links.  I remove parts of the path I find out that:

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/

This doesn't exist.

What gives?  Is this a maven error or something to do with Grails?  Are we experiencing an outage that will be fixed or is this something that I have to tell someone is broke?

Comment: Which version of grails are you using?

Comment: Grails 2.3.5.  I think it was a blip on maven side.  My build machine seems to be happy again.  I still get a 404 for those links though when I put them into a web browser.

Comment: Are you still getting errors?

Comment: Doesn't appear so.  So I don't know what caused the problem.